# What Meson command(s) is Gnome Builder running?

Tags: ninja, meson-build, flatpak, gnome-builder

Exactly what command(s) does Builder run internally when I press Run?

In the Builder (43.1 Flatpak) side pane there is this list of tasks:

[image: Build sequence]

To build my project I click (yes, with the mouse :/) on the last item, all the undone items are done in sequence, and I get thrown in a shell window where my build lives. And that's very nice, but:

For each of those steps, it would be even nicer if Builder would allow me to see (like in some sort of tooltip? But just in the output logs would be fine) exactly what it is that it's doing, or going to do.

So what I meant is: I **really** need to know the exact sequence of build command(s) that Builder is running to be able to build independently of the IDE / Editor ; like in a CI / CD pipeline.

It's clearly a combination of `meson this` and `ninja that`, but which one *exactly*? Is there a way to find out? I looked everywhere, also it's a Flatpak version so there are no command-line options or logs..?

Answer (score 0):

I also would like to find out which commands. So far, I was able to reproduce the build and installation running the following commands from the command line:

```
project_folder $ meson setup build_folder 
project_folder $ meson compile -C build_folder
project_folder $ meson install -C build_folder
```

I'm building a simple learning project using Rust + GTK4 + Gnome Builder. The project was generated with Gnome Builder. I´m running Gnome Builder 45.0 (FLATPAK) on Fedora 39